# How allow to use https for ASP.NET Core 2.1 in docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core-2.1

I use all the default settings that are created in VS2017(Dockerfile). Docker container in the Windows system (locally) is launched with support for https. But when I publish an application on the digital ocean, only unprotected mode works(only http). I have not found any relevant practical material on the net how to set it up. Can anyone help on this issue?